# question about AM-GM inequality ab<(a^2+b^2)/2

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

I have a question about the AM-GM inequality if a,b>0 then

1. ab≤(a+b)^2/4;
2. ab≤a^2+b^2;

I wonder if these 2 inequality are true for all a,b>0, if not which one is correct?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that by AM-GM inequality, if $c,d>0$ then ;
$$\sqrt{cd}\leq \frac{c+d}{2}$$
Substitute $c = a^2 ; d = b^2$ for $a,b>0$ to get
$$ab\leq \frac{a^2+b^2}{2} $$
$$\implies 2ab\leq a^2+b^2$$
$$\implies 4ab \leq a^2+b^2+2ab = (a+b)^2$$
$$ \implies ab\leq \frac{(a+b)^2}{4}$$
Hence first inequality is true.
Now note the second equation that is
$$ab\leq \frac{a^2+b^2}{2} $$
But $\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}<a^2+b^2$ this implies
$$ab< a^2+b^2$$
Hence the second inequality in your question is also true but without the equality sign.

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, why not look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements? Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.

Comment: @Snaw I apologise for this behaviour. I'll definitely keep in mind next time before posting any answer.

Comment: @Snaw  I'm so sorry for not clearly read announcement. I'll be careful.

Comment: @AmritAwasthi Thanks for your answer. I know where I got confused. Thanks!